# faster method to import data from text file

Tags: c#

I have to import data from a text file to a flat file database. I'm sure there's a faster way to load all the data into the database but I don't know how.

```
private void ImportButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Path = string.Empty;

    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "Text File|*.txt";
    ofd.ShowDialog();

    if (ofd.FileName == string.Empty) return

    Path = ofd.FileName;

    string data;
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(Path))
    {
        data = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    var items = data.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    var count = 0;
    foreach (var info in items.Select(ItemInfo.FromText).Where(info => info != null))
    {
        count++;
        info.Index = ++Envir.ItemIndex;
        Envir.ItemInfoList.Add(info);
    }

    MessageBox.Show(count + " Items have been imported");
    UpdateInterface(true);
}
```

Comment: That looks like it would be pretty fast. You could make the code smaller by writing `var items = File.ReadAllLines(Path);`.

Comment: `Envir.ItemInfoList.Add(info);` - Is this where you are writing to the db?

Comment: You don't say how Envir.ItemInfoList is implemented. If it's a synchronous call to something like Entity Framework, then that step could be improved. Does the DB support bulk insert? Investigate that.

Comment: @PaulHicks That's where I was going with my question. It's the only significant improvement I can think of.

Comment: isn't it better to read per line, than read the whole thing and split into array?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this via C#, then I'd recommend SqlBulkCopy. I provided a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8396165/685760) to another question a while back. See that link for an example of how I've implemented it in the past.

If you want to know other options available to you then MSDN has quite a good list of options in their data loading guide; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070(v=sql.100).aspx